# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user 'username' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I try to connect to my pg database using User.connection or generic-table.connection  I get this error

PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user 'username'

I double checked my database.yml and it looks good.  I think the problem lies with my pg_bha.conf file?  I can not find this file in my app or my system right now.

database.yml

```
    development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:

 test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username: name
  password:

 production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username: name
  password:

 cucumber:
   <<: *TEST
  Thanks for the help.
```

Comment: can you post your database.yml code

Answer (score 5):

First, to find your pg_hba.conf :

`sudo find / -name "pg_hba.conf"`

It is /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf on my system.

Make sure to change this line in pg_hba.conf :

`local   all             all                                     local`

to :

`local   all             all                                     md5`

Lastly, restart postgresql :

**OS X:**

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist`

**Systemd:**

`sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`

**SysVinit:**

`sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: Under Ubuntu 14.04, use the SysVinit command above to restart your PostgreSQL service. Also, thanks so much, this worked magnificently.

Answer (score 1):

I used this tutorial ["How To Setup Ruby on Rails with Postgres"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres)

And in my database.yml inserted this line:

```
........
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
username: user
password: password
pool: 5
host: localhost
.........
```