# psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, psql

I tried 5+ times to authenticate with a simple password. Failing that, I then reset the password and tried again:

```
owner@G700:~/cp/projFolder$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# alter user ctvmUser with password '1234';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \q

owner@G700:~/cp/projFolder$ psql -U ctvmUser -W -d callTrackVoipMs -a -f /home/owner/cp/projFolder/src/databaseScripts/createTables.sql;
Password: 
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ctvmUser"
```

After this attempt I tried copy/pasting 1234 and it still produced the same error.

I suspect something else is the issue. What else could prevent me from authenticating with psql?

I'm running PostgreSQL 12 on Lubuntu 20.04 locally (and the intended database interaction is local).

#### Other attempts

**No -W flag**

```
owner@G700:~/cp/projFolder$ psql -U ctvmUser -d callTrackVoipMs -a -f /home/owner/cp/projFolder/src/databaseScripts/createTables.sql;
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ctvmUser"
```

**Updating pg_hba.conf**

[PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user 'username' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411333/pgconnectionbad-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-username-error)

The line `local all all local` was not found:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

**Add -h flag with `localhost` argument**

First I added this line to the very end of the file `pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

-h flag with `localhost`, and output:

```
owner@G700:~/cp/voip_call_track_backend$ psql -U ctvmUser -d callTrackVoipMs -a -f /home/owner/cp/voip_call_track_backend/src/databaseScripts/createTables.sql -h localhost;
Password for user ctvmUser: 

psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ctvmUser"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ctvmUser"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add `-h localhost` or `-h 127.0.0.1` to psql arguments, so that this authentication rule can apply:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

(md5 implies that a password is requested).

When you omit the -h options, it connects by default to an Unix domain socket, so the connection attempt is matched against the `local all all peer` line. "peer" means that the OS user must be the same as the database user (which is not the case because of `-U ctvmUser`) and that the password is ignored.

Alternatively, if you prefer local users being authenticated with passwords, replace `local all all peer` with `local all all md5`.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the top post with the error after carefully entering `1234` as the password

Comment: @SeanD: check the exact case of the username in the database (\du in psql). It's probably `ctvmuser`, not `ctvmUser`. Then use -U ctvmuser on the command line. The command line is case sensitive whereas SQL does case-folding (case insensitive unless names are enclosed in double quotes).

Comment: yes you are right, i also had to lowercase the dbname, thank you